# Ubuntu 22.04 terminal stopped opening when launched from the desktop

Tags: nautilus, ssd, gnome-terminal

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.1 on AMD64 PC with 2 SSDs. The terminal worked just fine until I removed one of the SSDs (backup). Trying to launch Terminal by clicking on an icon in Favorites or by searching by name results in about 10s of a spinning timepiece and no terminal opening. I can open it by going to Nautilus and choosing `Open in Terminal`, though. Is there a fix for it?

Comment: Install an alternative terminal, e.g. xterm, then start gnome-terminal from there. Error messages may then possible indicate what might be wrong.

Comment: @vanadium I installed xterm, successfully started gnome-terminal from there, there was also a system update in the meantime and the problem disappeared.